# Automorphism group for a family of bigraphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Extend the sides of a regular polygon on 2m vertices, m ≥ 2,  to define the 2m(m - 1) finite points of intersection. Circumscribe a centrally symmetric circle large enough all of the points of intersection are in its interior. The 4m points of intersection of the extended edges of the polygon with the circle are the vertices of a bigraph, Pm. The edges are the 4m arcs of the circle between the vertices and the 2m diagonals defined by the extended edges.  P2 is the edge skeleton of the 3-cube, Q3. P3 is the Franklin graph. The Automorphism group of both Q3 and the Franklin graph is Z2 × S4. It is obvious that Z2 is a factor of the automorphism group for all Pm but is there an easy way to show what the other factor is for any of the other cases?

Comment: Certainly not in *all* cases. There's an obvious $C_{2m}$ contained.

Comment: The graphical description of the Pm was chosen since it was the most succinct description possible of the family and because it makes obvious two of the symmetries of the Pm: a rotation by two positions or a reflection about any of the 2m axis of symmetry is an identity. There are of course many other representations that reveal other symmetries. Wolfram MathWorld gives seven for the Franklin graph alone.